# What .ts file to edit in Ionic for plugin use?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, gps, ionic4

I am new to Ionic development and am trying to learn. I am creating a basic app to just display GPS coordinates to learn basic IOnic development.

So far I have a basic layout all figured out and I am now trying to learn how to incorporate the [geolocation plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation).

The "Usage" section give you some basic code to use to implement the plugin but I am not sure what file it goes into.

I am editing my simple app main page layout in ionic->gpsTest->src->app->home

And I am editing the home.page.html file. When I edit that file and use `ionic serve` command it shows my app in the web browser and it looks nice. But now where to edit the javascript for the page in the ionic structure?

I then went to [this tutorial](https://www.techiediaries.com/mobiledev/ionic-native-geolocation/) for help on adding a gps plugin.

But when I get to the part that says:

> Now to use the Geolocation API you have to import it from the
>   ionic-native module so go ahead and open the home.ts file or wherever
>   you want to your code for accessing Geolocation features and add this
>   line of code:

I do not know what .ts file to edit. In my ionic->gpsTest->src->app->home directory have have three .ts files

1. home.module.ts
2. home.page.spec.ts
3. home.page.ts

Update:

After doing some more research I found this article [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-your-first-ionic-4-app-with-api-calls-f6ea747dc17a). That article helped teach me about the Ionic structure.

I then edited my home.module.ts file to look like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';


import { HomePage } from './home.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}


constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation) {}

Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((data) => {
            console.log('My latitude : ', data.coords.latitude);
            console.log('My longitude: ', data.coords.longitude);
        });
```

But when I try to run it in the browser I get this error:

```
Cannot GET /
```

**Update2:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Geolocation,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Set it as a provider in home.module.ts and import in home.page.ts just like any other service / provider. Just add `ngx` at the end - `import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';`

Comment: @JuliusDzidzevičius since this is my first try at ionic, its not that obvious to me.

Not sure what you mean by just set it as a provider.

Comment: then you should run some basic tutorial first... like https://www.joshmorony.com/when-to-use-providersservicesinjectables-in-ionic/

Comment: @JuliusDzidzevičius I did some more research and tried again but got an actual error this time.

Comment: Geolocation is your provider, not a static class, so here is wrong `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition...`. Run it inside ngOnInit and with lowercase - `this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition...`

Comment: Oh, and it also belongs in component, not module...

Answer (score 0):

in app.module.ts have you included Geolocation as a provider?

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Geolocation,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I just added it to  app.module.ts but I still get the same error. I posted the  app.module.ts coed under "Updaeg2"